# Jumping Multi-element slices in Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

So say i have an array:

```
arr = np.arange(12)
```

And at the end I want this array:

```
arr2 = [0,1,2,6,7,8]
```

So I want a jumping mulitple slice, something like:

```
arr2 = arr[(0:2):-1:6]
```

where the second array is a slice of three that jumps 6 everytime.
Is this possible in numpy?

My actual example is a more complex example where part of the math is applied for the slice (0:2) that jumps 6 and the other math is applied to the slice (3:5) with a goal to write in one line i.e. without a for-loop.

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I'm having trouble finding documentation on this and I think I might just be googling the wrong thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `complex example`? Are you still jumping for those?

Comment: Does the jump length divide the total length?

Comment: The jump length is always 2x the slice length.  The whole array is ~100 jumps long.

Comment: Also the complex example is a gaussian operator where there's a different sigma value for the two slices.  The jumping nature stays the same.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344901/.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with slice notation, at least not directly.

But with some reshaping:

```
In [74]: arr = np.arange(12)                                                    
In [75]: arr.reshape(-1,3)                                                      
Out[75]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [76]: arr.reshape(-1,3)[::2,:]                                               
Out[76]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [77]: _.reshape(-1)                                                          
Out[77]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8])
```

Individually slicing and reshaping make `views`, but at some point in this transition, it has to make a copy.  So the timing relative to the advanced indexing that Divakar suggests is, at best, modest:

```
In [86]: timeit arr.reshape(-1,3)[::2,:].reshape(-1)                            
3.99 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [87]: timeit arr[(np.arange(len(arr))%6)<3]                                  
8.91 µs ± 89.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```