# In python how to delete a series of columns every nth element in a numpy 3d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344901/delete-a-series-of-elements-every-nth-time-in-numpy-array), say I have a 3D Numpy array, above which I've added a comment label for clarity:

```
          #C  C  C  R  R  C  C  C  R  R  C  C  C
    a = [[[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
          [23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35]],                

         [[36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48],
          [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60]],

         [[61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73],
          [74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86]]]
```

can I delete the columns labelled `R` in one line of code? So delete two columns every fifth element starting at index 3. In this case, the resulting array would look like this:

```
          #C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C
    a = [[[10,11,12,15,16,17,20,21,22],
          [23,24,25,28,29,30,33,34,35]],                

          [[36,37,38,41,42,43,46,47,48],
           [48,49,50,53,54,55,58,59,60]],

          [[61,62,63,66,67,68,71,72,73],
           [74,75,76,79,80,81,84,85,86]]]
```

I'd like to make the code more generic so it can handle deleting pairs of columns in 3D arrays of varying sizes and locations. For this example, I can delete one column at a time using this:

```
    start = 3
    step = 5
    a = numpy.delete(big, numpy.s_[start:numpy.size(big, 2):step], 2)
    a = numpy.delete(a, numpy.s_[start:numpy.size(a, 2):step - 1], 2)
```

But is there a way to specify a range of columns for deletion and so complete the task in one line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty similar to the [`linked posted answer there`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345059/) -

```
In [4]: a[...,np.mod(np.arange(a.shape[-1]),5)<3]
Out[4]: 
array([[[10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22],
        [23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35]],

       [[36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48],
        [48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60]],

       [[61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73],
        [74, 75, 76, 79, 80, 81, 84, 85, 86]]])
```

Or shorter one -

```
a[...,(np.arange(a.shape[-1])%5)<3]
```

Making it generic/*parameterize* -

```
group_size = 5
ignore_size = 2
out = a[...,(np.arange(a.shape[-1])%group_size)<(group_size-ignore_size)]
```

Comment: Awesome @Divakar. The shorter one and the generic one do what I want! I was just about to edit my question to ask about making it generic. I'll do that anyway in case it encourages others to read further into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the indices you want:

```
a=a[:,:,[0,1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12]]
```

Or, in a more general way:

```
a=a[:,:,[i for i in range(13) if i%5 in [0,1,2]]]
```

output:

```
array([[[10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22],
        [23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35]],
       [[36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48],
        [48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60]],
       [[61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 71, 72, 73],
        [74, 75, 76, 79, 80, 81, 84, 85, 86]]])
```